# Social Network Android app:which Backend Service?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services, social-networking

Me and some friends are going to create a social networking app on Android.
We are at the beginning,and we wanted to start the project using a Backend Service offered by Amazon (AWS) or Google (Google App Engine),and maybe migrate to other solutions when our app will be in an advanced state.
This app includes all the features offered by a social network like uploading images,videos,status,etc.
What I wanted to ask is: how can I handle the data services related to the app?
What solutions are best for managing user info, user multimedial content,etc?
(We tought about some kind of datastore for the multimedial content,and a Relational Database for the other User Informations,but we're not sure about this).
Are AWS or Google App Engine possible ways to handle this type of content,and what service in particular would be the best?

Comment: Google App Engine is highly restricted as to what type of code you can run as it must be on their whitelist before the code can run. This can be difficult to use as there might be a library you might want to employ in your server side code but it cannot run on GAE because one of the dependencies in the library is not on GAE whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase is the simplest Backend as a service and free for up to 10 concurrent solutions.  It will scale to unlimited concurrent for a reasonable amount.  Firebase has good social sign on and security features.  Best part is that clients will update 'live' without having to refresh the page to see changes.  Parse.com is another free PAAS but does not have the real time features of Firebase.