# Can ordinary web hosting be used as a back end for android app?

Tags: android, hosting, backend

I want to make an android app (like tiktok) which needs its data (mostly images and videos) to be on cloud i.e. it must not be on local device. I have used Google Firebase but it will be costly because I need space in terabytes. I have read many Q/A at stackoverflow about it but most of them refer to use Firebase, Amazon or Parse. My question is can I use any ordinary hosting service like [godady](https://pk.godaddy.com/hosting/web-hosting) or [winshosting](https://www.winshosting.com/business-shared-hosting-plan.html) to store my videos and images data as these service provide unlimited space and bandwidth? If yes then godaddy is saying they include 1gb sql database storage in every hosting plane. 1 GB database but unlimited space and bandwidth is confusing as I need storage but not sure that I will need database or not. What is difference between storage and database storage given by these companies? [image: Screenshot]Screenshot included. Please suggest me whole solution according to the context. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33175526/social-network-android-appwhich-backend-service) and many similar question but confused.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its possible, if you only need the hosting for your storage

I know you mentioned Amazon and don't prefer it, but Amazon Cloud actually provides a decent price for its cloud storage https://blog.cloudability.com/aws-s3-understanding-cloud-storage-costs-to-save/

It also provides you with feasible Relational Database at cheap price and superpowered AWS Lambda for your API service which you will likely need.

Comment: DemiDust Thank You for reply. What is meant by "if you only need the hosting for your storage"? I just need storage for videos and ability to download and upload from android app. Please clarify.

Comment: Means you only need your server to store images, videos and your other contents, without any endpoint gateway